# Generics based classes

Tags: java, generics

If we are designing a class that will be used to create items in a generics-based collection what should we need for this and why?

Comment: Have you tried researching this question at all? I get tons of hits on Google.

Comment: you can probably get away with a simple text editor because that's really all you need for designing a class ;)

Answer (score 7):

You'll need an abstract factory class. Usually those are good for creating abstract wrappers for concrete types in a generic fashion. Factories are often implemented as singletons, too.